# Rounded corners for hover view in Android?

Tags: android, view, menu, customization

I want to set rounded menu corners in Android.

I already did that with a custom drawable and set it as menu background which works well.

drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius"/>
    <solid android:color="#FFF"/>
</shape>
```

themes.xml:

```
<style name="popupOverflowMenu" 
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/rounded_corners</item>
</style>

<item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/popupOverflowMenu</item>
```

But when I click on a menu item the grey hover view is still a rectangle so it hovers out of the menu background.

[image]

Is there an option to fix that?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: First of all post your code

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964594/how-do-i-make-the-rounded-corners-of-the-menu-in-the-toolbar/62892680#62892680